# Python xmltodict распарсить XML

Tags: python, xml

Мне нужно распарсить XML. Вот как выглядит он в сыром виде:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><NS1:GetBlockResponse xmlns:NS1="SysEtranInt"><return xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</return><Text xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?&gt;
&lt;error&gt;
&lt;errorCode value="4"/&gt;
&lt;errorMessage value="Накладная с ID=1 не найдена или у Вас нет прав доступа к данному документу."/&gt;
&lt;errorStatusCode value="404"/&gt;
&lt;/error&gt;
</Text></NS1:GetBlockResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Вот этот же XML после форматирования:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <NS1:GetBlockResponse xmlns:NS1="SysEtranInt">
         <return xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</return>
         <Text xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?&gt;
&lt;error&gt;
&lt;errorCode value="4"/&gt;
&lt;errorMessage value="Накладная с ID=1 не найдена или у Вас нет прав доступа к данному документу."/&gt;
&lt;errorStatusCode value="404"/&gt;
&lt;/error&gt;</Text>
      </NS1:GetBlockResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Я хочу превратить его в dict при помощи питоновской библиотеки xmltodict. Вот как я это делаю:

```
body = mk_request(invoiceReturnEmptyCarrige)
doc = xmltodict.parse(body)
print(doc["Envelope"])
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

> KeyError: 'Envelope'

Как правильно работать с этой библиотекой и обращаться к интересующим тэгам с данными? Цель - добраться до тэга Text.

Comment: `print(doc['SOAP-ENV:Envelope'])` - у меня работает

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть на `doc.keys()`

Comment: `print(doc['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['NS1:GetBlockResponse']['Text'])` - как я понимаю - то, что надо

Comment: а если с помощью ElementTree из стандартной библиотеки получить содержимое `<Text>`?